# change page title of page when it shows default archive title

Tags: wordpress

"The default shop page is a archive for the products post type which doesn't carry a page title."

i installed a theme and configured basic settings, now when i click on shop page, the page title is ‘product archive’, i have installed all in one seo plugin to change its page title, but it does nt change.

is there a way to change page title of archives…

http://www.islamoverflow.com/muslim-shop-online/

Comment: did you try if is_shop() condition?

Comment: see this https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-is_shop.html